# How to change swipe direction in swiper.js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6, swiper.js

I'm struggling with changing swipe direction when I rotate  my swiper on 90deg. So in the beginning by default it has horizontal direction. When clicking on slide I'm rotating "swiper-container" making it  full screen .  So it still has swiping direction from left to right , but I need to change from top to bottom without changing in params direction to vertical .

```
const topSwiper = new Swiper(this.DOMTopSwiper.current, {
  spaceBetween: 0,
  observer: true,
  observeParents: true,
  observeSlideChildren: true,
  direction: "vertical",
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".top-swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".top-swiper-button-prev",
  },
  pagination: {
    el: ".zoom-amount-slides",
    type: "fraction",
  },
})
```

Comment: Why dont you instead of rotating the container, use the device orientation api and forces the device to be rotated? Here's an example on how you could use it.. https://www.jotform.com/blog/html5-screen-orientation-api-uses-javascript-to-rotate-the-screen-89639/

Comment: Why are you rotating this to begin with? Am I supposed to tilt my head at a 90° angle now to be able to properly see the content …?

Comment: @anderson-ivan-witzke window.screen.orientation is experimental API and is not supported in some browsers

Comment: What do you mean by `when I rotate my swiper on 90deg`? Is it a mobile device that you rotate from portrait to landscape?

Answer (score 9):

Destroy previous Swiper and reinitialize Swiper giving the direction value. Here is [doc](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/)

***DEMO***

```js
let isVertical = true,
  direction = 'vertical';
let swiper = initSwiper(direction);

function initSwiper(direction) {
  return new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    spaceBetween: 50,
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      clickable: true,
    },
    direction: direction
  });

}

function changeDirection() {
  isVertical = !isVertical;
  direction = isVertical ? 'vertical' : 'horizontal';
  let slideIndex = swiper.activeIndex;
  swiper.destroy(true, true);
  swiper = initSwiper(direction);
  swiper.slideTo(slideIndex,0);
}
```

```css
html, body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.swiper-container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.6/css/swiper.min.css">
<!-- Swiper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.6/js/swiper.js"></script>
<button onclick='changeDirection()'>Change Direction</button>
<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @yerlan-yeszhanov wants to rotate the picture itself, not only change the slider direction

Comment: @Durga thanks for demo but as mentioned above "without changing in params direction to vertical " .

Comment: @YerlanYeszhanov, did you find any problem with that?

Comment: @Durga you mean like a cube

Answer (score 2):

For who's searching this in 2022, now is possible to update direction using  `swiper.changeDirection('vertical'); // or horizontal`

complete example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-demo-43-change-direction

Answer (score 1):

Just simply add reverseDirection: true, in the autoplay

```
autoplay: {
        delay: 0,
      disableOnInteraction: true,
      reverseDirection: true,
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my solution.

```js
//Tested in Swiper 7.2.0
/**
 * Insert to your page
 */
var rotate90Swiper = (function (swiper, optIsRotate90) {
    var isRoate90 = !!optIsRotate90
    swiper.___touches = {}
    swiper.___touches.currentX = swiper.touches.currentX
    Object.defineProperty(swiper.touches, 'currentX', {
        set: function (v) {
            if (!isRoate90) {
                swiper.___touches.currentX = v
            } else {

                swiper.___touches.currentY = v
            }

        },
        get: function () {
            return swiper.___touches.currentX
        }
    })
    swiper.___touches.currentY = swiper.touches.currentY
    Object.defineProperty(swiper.touches, 'currentY', {
        set: function (v) {
            if (!isRoate90) {
                swiper.___touches.currentY = v
            } else {
                swiper.___touches.currentX = v
            }
        },
        get: function () {
            return swiper.___touches.currentY
        }
    })
    return function (b) {
        isRoate90 = b
    }
})

/**
 * How to use
 */
var setRotate90 = rotate90Swiper(YourSwiperInstance, defaultIsRotate90)
setRotate90(false) // swiper rotate 90deg
setRotate90(true)   //normal swiper
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick edit if you need to rotate at 180 your swiperjs

```
var rotate180Swiper = (function (swiper, optIsRotate180) {
        var isRoate180 = !!optIsRotate180
        swiper.___touches = {}
        swiper.___touches.currentX = swiper.touches.currentX
        Object.defineProperty(swiper.touches, 'currentX', {
                set: function (v) {
                        if (!isRoate180) {
                                swiper.___touches.currentX = -v
                        } else {

                                swiper.___touches.currentX = v
                        }

                },
                get: function () {
                        return swiper.___touches.currentX
                }
        })

        return function (b) {
                isRoate180 = b
        }
})
```